# Better way than using on() and off() to only bind scroll event in if-clause?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-events

I want to listen to a window scroll event only if a certain statement is true, let's say `var flag`. I think I'd do it like this, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

```
$(window).on("scroll", someFunction());
if (flag) $(window).off("scroll");
```

Or, possibly better,

```
if (flag) $(window).on("scroll", someFunction());
```

Comment: Using the flag inside or outside depends on how frequently you need to turn on/off the scroll handler? You could throttle the scroll event and call the handler instead of calling the handler function on each scroll. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: How are you currently performing task? Which portion is not returning expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this question hugely depends on the scenario. There are 3 items we need to consider before jumping into a solution,

1. How frequently the scroll handler function needs to be turned on/off
2. With scroll event it will be called multiple times. Do you need your handler function to be called on every scroll or can it be throttled?
3. How heavy is your handler function?

**How frequently the scroll handler function needs to be turned on/off?** We could use a flag,

1. bind/unbind/rebind/so...on using a flag
2. inside the handler to execute the function

You could decide on one of the above approach after testing your scenario. It would depend on how frequently the functionality will be turned on/off.

**Do you need your handler function to be called on every scroll?**
Throttle allows you to execute your handler function once every X seconds. This is better than calling the function onscroll.

Throttle is good in this case. Even better, if your throttle is more than a few seconds, you could combine the 1a. (bind/unbind/rebind) after every throttle seconds. Again, all this timing depends on your scenario.

**Handler function** If the handler function is big, then I would look for an alternate approach instead of binding it to the scroll event. Remember, JavaScript execution is going to stop the page from responding, so even if your script takes few milliseconds, executing it on every scroll (no throttle, e.t.c) will slow your page and makes is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Both binding and unbinding scroll event have cost. Calling handler on event also has cost. But what is more important is clarity of the code you have and responsiveness of the app that you need to achieve.

Applications feels smooth if you can get to those 60 fps. So I would keep whatever code you find to be clear and aligned with your codebase and just do some performance testing to see if you are getting 60 fps with those scroll handlers, and fix performance issues should you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Because add/remove event handler are quite costly and you have to write more code to prevent event handler is added more than one times. So I suggest more simple solution, add event one time and check your `flag` at begin of handler.

```
$(window).on("scroll", someFunction());
function someFunction() {
    if (!flag) return;
}
```

This way you can stop scroll event by simply call `flag = false;` at anytime, anywhere in you code.

Answer (score 0):

If what you stated,

> I want to **listen** to a window scroll event **only if** a certain statement
>   is **true** ...

is indeed what you want, then use your second block of code.

> ```
> if (flag) $(window).on("scroll", someFunction());
> ```

If you are trying to conditionally call the handler onscroll, then do something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/vffLtdy3/),